# error while installing mysql 8 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, mysql

I am trying to install Mysql 8 on my ubuntu 18.04.
I uninstalled every previous Mysql installations and make sure there is nothing related to sql on my mchine by executing

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep mysql
```

Next, to install Mysql I issued following commands

```
$ sudo wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb
$ sudo apt-get update
```

all work fine till here, but when I issue this

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

I am getting this error. I tried this on two different ubuntu machines and I am getting same error. Can someone guide what mistake I am doing?

```
    dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
 installed mysql-community-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 8.0.19-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Looks like you need to send that info as a bug report to packaging team. Not sure if we can do much.

Comment: I am getting this on two different Ubuntu machines. Has anyone else tested mysql 8 ?

Comment: I have been using MySQL 8 since an year and faced no problem so far. It seems some error messages are missing from here. What is the output of `sudo dpkg --configure mysql-community-server`?

Comment: @Kulfy I'm getting the same issue: `dpkg --configure mysql-community-serverme
Setting up mysql-community-server (8.0.20-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service → /lib/sys
temd/system/mysql.service.
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your case, but I've had similar results while trying to install  MySQL 8 on Ubuntu 20.04. The cause appeared to be insufficient RAM - I had only 512M in my setup. Then I arranged a swap file (using [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-20-04)) - and the installation passed smoothly.